# "We couldn't get your developer license for Windows 8", error 0xC03F1014

Tags: windows

Whenever I try to get my developer's license in Windows 8 Professional with WMC for Visual Studio Ultimate with Blend, I get this error:

> We couldn't get your developer license for Windows 8. (Error 0xC03F1014)

How do I fix this error to get my developer's license?

Comment: Why so many caps? To me its more effort to do that then to type all lowercase.

Comment: .Net Developers Always Write CAPS :D:D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your copy of Windows 8 is cracked or activated illegitimately then you'll get this error.

If for whatever reason you don't want to / can't get a legitimate copy, then deactivating the crack to go back to the trial period, acquiring the license then re-activating it should fix this issue.

Comment: This might be one of the reasons too

Comment: Mine is cracked. Googled around, spent 20 minutes. Done nothing to change the situation, gave it another go and it went through. I am now a licensed dev for 6 months. lol!

Answer (score 4):

Try to follow these steps:

1. Create a temporary user account in windows 8
2. Install a fresh copy of VS 2012

Now try again. It should work now, then log out again and go back to your normal account. Now develop apps and deploy it. Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: This worked for me.  The "temporary" account I used was an admin account.  Don't know if that matters though.

Answer (score 1):

**You need not re-install the OS or the Visual Studio**

Start the Task Scheduler service. This is usually disabled in enterprises/large organizations via Group Policy.

Answer (score 1):

This situation happened to me after installing Windows 8 Pro Upgrade as a CLEAN installation.  The problem was that the valid License Key failed to activate because a previous version of windows was not upgraded.  Because it wasn't activated properly, the Developer License would also not register.

The following steps enabled me to activate the clean install:

1. Run the registry editor (regedit)
2. Find the following key: 
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\OOBE
3. Change the value for 'MediaBootInstall' from 1 to 0
4. Open an elevated command prompt (run as admin)
5. Run the following command: slmgr -rearm
6. Reboot
7. Open an elevated command prompt (run as admin)
8. Run the following command: slui 3
9. Activate your valid Window 8 Pro Upgrade License Key

After my Windows 8 was properly activated, the Developer License renewed with no problems!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. Error was due to Proxy Server. I was using internet by setting proxy server. U should have open internet to get the developer license.

Answer (score 0):

See these type off error occurred to me . The scenario was I was connected to a proxy server and my proxy server was not allowing popup logins .
Check your internet connection and If the problem is not solved, reinstall VS

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio 2012 as administrator.  It should prompt you automatically for the license.  I had to login to my MSDN account at this time.  If it doesn't come up, then go to Project -> Store -> Acquire Developmer License.  This is what did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, with the additional information that there was a problem with the network (even though my network was fine).

For me, the problem was that my own user is a limited/normal user and doesn't have administrator rights. I did get a UAC prompt when I tried to get a license and I elevated the process to use my separate administrator account, but it didn't work.

What did work however was *logging out* from my normal user, *signing in as my administrator account* and try to get a developer license that way.

So apparently running under a non-privileged user is not something that VS2013 appreciates in scenarios like this. I'm not sure why there is a difference between elevating a process' rights through UAC and actually logging in as an elevated user.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all Windows Updates installed. If you can't update:

- **Install KB2913270 ([x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41575)/[x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41577))** ([original info by Ahmad Wahid](http://www.windows8core.com/microsoft-releases-bug-fixing-update-windows-store-windows-8-1rt-download-now/), thanks :))

Other tips:

- Check the system date and time (it must not be ahead on their systems)
- Try to disable NlaSvc service (Network Location Awareness)